# Alfresco: Modifying email link

Tags: email, alfresco

I have deployed a custom workflow, and have email notifications correctly setup for each task. The email links currently look like the following:

https://myCompany.com/share/page/task-details?taskId=activiti$58788

This link takes the user to the details view of the task, and requires them to hit the "Edit" button at the bottom to actually perform the task. Ideally, I would like to change the link to the following:

https://myCompany.com/share/page/task-edit?taskId=activiti$58788

As task-edit allows them to immediately edit the form and perform the task. How might I go about making this change (for just this workflow)?

Comment: you can change link from your custom workflow , from where you are sending notification.There will be an email template or custom mail action.

Comment: I believe it comes from the activiti:candidateGroups property of my userTask elements in the .bpmn file. Does that sound right?

Comment: I also located in my model, the override <property name="bpm:sendEMailNotifcations"> is defaulted to true.

Comment: Where can I find the email templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the email template(s) for all notifications: **wf-email.html.ftl** located in `Data dictionary/Email templates/Workflow notification`

Change the following html snippet:

```
<a href="${shareUrl}/page/task-details?taskId=${args.workflowId}">${shareUrl}/page/task-details?taskId=${args.workflowId}</a>
```

Into

```
<a href="${shareUrl}/page/task-edit?taskId=${args.workflowId}">${shareUrl}/page/task-edit?taskId=${args.workflowId}</a>
```

If you're using your own notification mechanism, then create a new email template based on this one and use the path in your Mail task or JavaScript mail action.

**---UPDATE---**

You can use this JavaScript in you're workflow to send an email, still it's easier to use the AlfrescoMailtask.

```
// create mail action

var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to = "test@alfresco.com";
mail.parameters.subject = "You've got mail";
mail.parameters.from = "server@alfresco.com";
mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath("Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Workflow notification/My_custom_Template.ftl");
mail.parameters.text = "some text, in case template is not found";

// execute action against a document
mail.execute(document);
```

Comment: Great, this is almost everything I was looking for. Would it be possible to define this on a per-workflow basis? Ideally I only want "task-edit" emails for a certain workflow.

Comment: Or would it be best to disable the task-assigned emails, and execute javascript emails on a userTask basis?

Comment: Yeah sure, that's the second part, just implement the notify email action in your workflow and don't rely on the default.

Comment: I'd love to award you the bounty, but I need a bit more information. When I define a new email using Javascript, what code can I ues to force it to the edit link?